# System context of aggregated systems SysML

Tags: sysml

I'm currently trying to understand how to model a system context diagram the right way.

E.g. the System of Interest is a diagnosis system where vehicle data gets preprocessed onboard and some prediction model in the backend tells me if component x is fine or not.
Actors would be the vehicle driver/owner and a service employee and some external systems like a mobile app or service management system.

My main problem now is to get the system border right.

1. Systems which are part of the actual SoI, like vehicle and backend, should not appear in the context diagram, right?
2. If a small functional part of my SoI (like the backend detects defect component x and sends the information including recommendations for actions to the service system to inform the employee) is assigned to an external system (like service management system in this case) - is it still a external system? How do I model relations like that and is there a guideline at which "participation" level my external system becomes an acutal part of my SoI?

Comment: There is no system context diagram in UML. This is a SysML concept